# Using Arrays to compare ordered pairs and determine mathematical systems

Tags: java

I am writing a program that takes ordered pairs and determines if they are Reflexive, Symmetric and Transitive...
Given these points: (1,1)(1,2)(2,2)(4,4)(2,1)(3,3)
Reflexive : all these are present: (1,1)(2,2)(3,3)(4,4)
Symmetric: if (a, b) is present then (b, a) is present
Transitive: if (a, b) and (b, c) is present then (a,c) must also be present... 
I am having problems because I started by using linked lists but decided that arrays would be easier. I was told to use the Point[] package, that it would make it easier than parallel arrays... this is what I have and i am not sure if it is even right?? i can't even seem to get numbers to store into my array!! Help please!!!

```
/****************************************************************
* Name: Cheryl Minor        Date: March 8, 2011
*
* Program: Write a program that checks whether a relation R
*   is an equivalence relation. If R is an equivalence relation
*   the program outputs the equivalence classes of R.
****************************************************************/
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Problem17 
{
static class Point{
    int x;
    int y;
}
public static void main(String []args)
{
    Point[] line = new Point[6];
    for(int i = 0; i<line.length; i++)
    {
        line[i] = new Point();
    }

    line[0].x = 1;
    line[1].x = 1;
    line[2].x = 2;
    line[3].x = 4;
    line[4].x = 2;
    line[5].x = 3;

    line[0].y = 1;
    line[1].y = 2;
    line[2].y = 2;
    line[3].y = 4;
    line[4].y = 1;
    line[5].y = 3;  

    System.out.println(line);   
   }
}
```

Comment: You would do well to give your Point class (1) a constructor that takes x and y values, and (2) accessors so that your code can get at the x and y values inside a Point. Aside from that, the code you've posted doesn't contain anything that even begins to try to solve the problem you've been set; you should at least have a go, and Stack Overflow will not do your homework for you.

Comment: i didn't really want it to tell me how to do all the for loops and stuff, i just wanted to make sure that my point class was written correctly...

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this. This algorithm can be improve but now is more readable:

```
Point[] list = new Point[5];
...
for (int i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    // checking Reflexive
    if (list[i].x == list[i].y) System.out.println("Reflexive" + list[i]);
    for (int j=i+1; j<list.length; j++) {
        // checking Symmetric
        if (list[i].x == list[j].y && list[i].y == list[j].x) ...
        for (int k=j+1; k<list.length; k++) {
            // checking Transitive
            if (list[i].x == list[k].x && list[i].y == list[j].x && ...
        }
    }
}
```

Small advice:

- add constructor Point(x,y)
- add toString in Point()

Comment: so i have this..
    System.out.println("Is it reflexive?");
    for(int i = 0; i<line.length; i++)
   {
     while(i<line.length)
     {
      if(line[i].x != line[i].y)
       return false;
     }
     return true;
    }
    
    
   
I understand using the triple for loops but it won't let me do the true/false thing.. says it can't return anything whose result type is void...

Comment: I've added a few lines in my algorithm, if you add to Point class toString method which print (x,y) then you will see Reflexive, I've added Symmetric you must change "..." by System.out.println, and reflexive is excercise :)

Answer (score 0):

There is one universal solution to all computer programs (aka: the golden bullet): divide et impera (invented by the romans).

Solve your problem step by step.

... a program that takes ordered pairs ... Given these points: (1,1)(1,2)(2,2)(4,4)(2,1)(3,3)

I have a first dissonance here. :)